# Unicode codes by Language

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization

I am writing a Java application which allows for user entry of Unicode characters `\uxxxx`.

If a user is entering (for instance) French, then they can use Unicode to enter French accented characters (`\u00c0` for  À). However if they do not know the coding for a character, I would like to present them with a dialogue which has a grid of the accented characters, let them click on one, then insert the Unicode into the text.

I have been trying to find a map of special characters by language and the various sites I have found do not seem to have this type of breakdown. Ideally I could download a list of character codes by language, parse it, and add it to my application.

Something like:

```
French \u00c0 \u00c2
```

Or

```
Spanish
&#192;
&#201;
```

Or any reasonable format. Any idea where I could get something like this?

Comment: It is difficult because there are many exceptions (e.g. locality names and surnames have exceptions, because of historical reasons). I would propose you to check Latin1 etc: you get the letters, and you will use such letters for all "Latin1" supported languages. Then you look the other ISO 8859 charset (e.g. in Wikipedia, and supported languages). This will make happy people near the borders, but it will create too many options for most of people. Else there are word list per language. Just extract the characters, and check/remove the less used one [look spelling libraries]

Comment: `&#xc0;` or `&#192;` or `\u00c0` is _Latin Capital Letter A With Grave_ in all languages…

Comment: Yes, I know there would be overlapping between languages for some characters. So I would show the overlapping characters in each language which uses them.

Comment: And so I kept looking and found this: http://www.eki.ee/letter/ which is almost exactly what I need.